# Track visitors across different domains using Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics, tracking, vwo

We provide a `<div>` block to our clients to put on their websites, which they then integrate into their site using a script that will generate the html.

For example:

```
<div class="currentDiv">

<script type="text/javascript" id="axxaax99" src="xxxx-xxx.js"></script>

</div>
```

How do I track the number of visitors in Google Analytics, through our `<div>` block that is placed on our clients websites?

Comment: You could possibly track when that specific class appears on a page and send off an event, thereby tracking loosely the number of visitors.

Comment: @nyuen and how im going to track the class with google analytics ?

Comment: You search for that element on the page, and if it's there, then fire your event. I'm not sure how much more I can explain without actually coding it for you.

Comment: @nyuen you are not here to code for me, and if u read my question well you will understand that i can tiger the even from my javascript but my question to trigger the tracking event cross domain names because the js code will be on the client website.

Comment: Sorry for any misunderstandings, but your post could use clarification. Why don't you show what you have tried so far as it is your obligation to show your code attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this and I want to share my solution to save other people time.

so first thing to do on client website is to check if google analytics is already there or we load it and then you can fire a page-event send using the tracker name that you already created.

```
<script type="text/javascript">                 
var appendAnalytics = function (i, s, o, g, r, cb) {                     i["GoogleAnalyticsObject"] = r;
i[r] = i[r] || function () {     (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)}, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
var a = s.createElement(o);
var m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
a.async = 1;
a.src = g;     
a.onload = cb;
m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)};     
if (window.ga === undefined) {     
appendAnalytics(window, document, "script", "//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js", "ga", sendPageView);
} else {     
sendPageView();
}     
function sendPageView() {     
window.ga("create", "UA-XXXXXX”, "auto", {     name: “YourTrackerName”                     });
window.ga("YourTrackerName.send", "pageview");     
}     
</script>
```